# Unusual behavior of standard library function abs() on different C++ compilers

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, libstdc++, std, libc++

Consider following program:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    int d = (int)(abs(0.6) + 0.5);
    printf("%d", d);
    return 0;
}
```

`g++` 7.2.0 Output 0 ( See live demo [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/H6jEzHS3eV0f8V4m) )

`g++` 6.3.0 ( See live demo [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DrctV9KhyHTFiZda) )

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:6:26: error: 'abs' was not declared in this scope
     int d = (int)(abs(0.6) + 0.5);
                          ^
prog.cc:6:26: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from prog.cc:2:0:
/opt/wandbox/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/cmath:103:5: note:   'std::abs'
     abs(_Tp __x)
     ^~~
```

`clang++` 5.0.0 Output 1 ( See live demo [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/33f0UBvov4KpYUsM) )

`clang++` 3.6.0 ( See live demo [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BSAZhuY5n9HdJEFm) )

```
prog.cc:6:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'abs'; did you mean 'fabs'?
    int d = (int)(abs(0.6) + 0.5);
                  ^~~
                  fabs
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:181:14: note: 'fabs' declared here
__MATHCALLX (fabs,, (_Mdouble_ __x), (__const__));
             ^
/usr/include/math.h:71:26: note: expanded from macro '__MATHCALLX'
  __MATHDECLX (_Mdouble_,function,suffix, args, attrib)
                         ^
/usr/include/math.h:73:22: note: expanded from macro '__MATHDECLX'
  __MATHDECL_1(type, function,suffix, args) __attribute__ (attrib); \
                     ^
/usr/include/math.h:76:31: note: expanded from macro '__MATHDECL_1'
  extern type __MATH_PRECNAME(function,suffix) args __THROW
                              ^
/usr/include/math.h:79:42: note: expanded from macro '__MATH_PRECNAME'
#define __MATH_PRECNAME(name,r) __CONCAT(name,r)
                                         ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h:88:23: note: expanded from macro '__CONCAT'
#define __CONCAT(x,y)   x ## y
                        ^
1 error generated.
```

Microsoft VC++ 19.00.23506 Output 1 ( See live demo [here](http://rextester.com/DSVV79869) )

What exactly is happening here in this program ? Why it gives different output when compiled on different C++ compilers ? Why program exhibits different behavior even on different version of same compiler ? Is this compiler issue or standard library (`libstdc++` & `libc++`) issue ? What C++ standard says about this ?

**P.S:** I know that I need to write `std::abs` instead of `abs`. But this is not my question.

Comment: The math headers are far from uniform. g++ actually being the most non-standard instead of VS for once.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All the `cname` library headers that bring in functionality from the C standard library must introduce those symbols in namespace `std`. They also *may*, but definitely not *must* introduce them into the global namesapce. [[headers]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/headers#4):

> Except as noted in Clauses [library] through [thread] and Annex
>   [depr], the contents of each header cname is the same as that of the
>   corresponding header name.h as specified in the C standard library. In
>   the C++ standard library, however, the declarations (except for names
>   which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope of the
>   namespace std. It is unspecified whether these names (including any
>   overloads added in Clauses [language.support] through [thread] and
>   Annex [depr]) are first declared within the global namespace scope and
>   are then injected into namespace std by explicit using-declarations.

So different compilers, and even different compiler versions, mean different implementation details.

Comment: so it is quite possible that behavior of program may change if compiler & library gets upgraded & it will be still considered standard confirming. right ?

Comment: @Destructor - Yes. Only way to get guaranteed behavior is via namespace `std`

Comment: For a more in-depth look, consider that `abs` was essentially split between `<stdlib.h>` and `<math.h>` in C. C++ also added integral overloads to `<cmath>` per [LWG 2192](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2192). Also consider that `<cstdlib>` might be included from one of the two headers included in the question, and this can easily vary per implementation and version. `abs` was one of the things described in [Redhat's article](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/02/29/why-cstdlib-is-more-complicated-than-you-might-think/) about changing GCC's handling of C headers.

Comment: @chris: It will be better if you write your answer

Comment: @Destructor, Such an answer would be most useful with the precise situation of each case in the question, but I don't have that information. I can only conjecture based on the output that some implementations pick the integral version, causing an output of 0, and some pick the `double` version, causing an output of 1. It's hard for me to say exactly why either is picked in each case without spending a lot of time on it, especially with the implementation-definedness of whether global names are available for the C++ versions.